# Ricoh Theta S doesn't accept new options

Tags: sdk, postman, theta360

I'm having problems with JSON and Postman when I'm trying to test camera settings. Every time when I change settings, the picture is always the same.  If I change shutter speed to value 0.0002 (which should be shutter speed 1/5000) the result is the same as on 0.1 (1/10).

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "name" : "camera.setOptions",
    "parameters" : {
        "sessionId": "SID_0001",
        "options" : {
            "clientVersion" : 2,
              "_autoBracket": {
        "_bracketNumber": 3,
        "_bracketParameters": [
            {
             "exposureProgram" : 1,
                "shutterSpeed": 0.1,
                "iso": 400,
                "exposureCompensation" : 0,
                "whiteBalance" : "_colorTemperature",
                "_colorTemperature": 5100
            },
            {
             "exposureProgram" : 1,
                "shutterSpeed": 0.1,
                "iso": 320,
                "exposureCompensation" : 0,
                "whiteBalance" : "_colorTemperature",
                "_colorTemperature": 5100
            },
            {
             "exposureProgram" : 1,
                "shutterSpeed": 0.1,
                "iso": 1600,
                "exposureCompensation" : 0,
                "whiteBalance" : "_colorTemperature",
                "_colorTemperature": 5000
            }
        ]
    }
        }
    }
}
```

Once I submit those settings using `camera.execute.setOptions`, the reply says that the settings have been successfuly changed, yet when I try to take a picture using `camera.execute.takePicture`, the picture turns out to be the same as on default settings. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `_autoBracket` option you have to use `camera.startCapture` with parameter `"_mode" : "bracket"` and not `camera.takePicture` as when taking ordinary photos

```
{
    "name" : "camera.startCapture",
    "parameters" : {
    "_mode" : "bracket"
    }
}
```